# Android Tabs Content for better User Experience

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have an Activity which has 3 tabs which are Fragments.

1. Featured
2. Up Coming
3. Favorites

Right now my implement when i click a particular tab it downloads the content from the internet and displays it.

When i was browsing through the Google Play App. I found that when i went into the App section All the content across the tabs `Featured - Top Free - Top Paid etc` was already there and only the images was lazy loading.

I am trying figure out how this can be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my app i have a Activity wich has 4 Tabs wich are Fragments..

I solved your explained Problem by Using a Singleton. I load all relevant information from sqlite database and pass it into an ArrayList in the Singletion..
So i can access the content  from every Fragment...

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance = null;

    public ArrayList<MyObject> myObjectList;

    protected Singleton() {
        // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
    }
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new Singleton();
                    myObjectList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)